# Python 2.7 windows installer requires elevated privileges

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does Python 2 installation require elevated(admin) privileges while Python 3.5 can be installed for the current user without elevation.

Is it from the strategy by PSF to promote Python 3 by undermining Python 2 ?

Comment: They should both require admin privileges. They try to install to the C drive, which isn't writable without an administrative account

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope. You can change the installation path. Have you installed before ?

Comment: Yes, you can change it, but that's the default

Comment: probably because the 3.5 installer has had five more releases' worth of work done on it than the 2.7 installer.  no longer actively developing a maintenance-mode old release is pretty typical, and not usually construed as a form of sabotage

Answer (score 4):

Python 2 installs to C:\Python27 or similar. This requires admin privileges.

Python 3 installs to your user profile by default. This doesn't require admin privileges (I can never remember exactly where it is, though).

They changed the default install location in Python 3 to improve the user experience. I am pretty sure that they did not travel back in time to make the Python 2 experience worse in order to promote Python 3.